# Use the values of an array from a function using scanf and pass it to the main function

Tags: c, string, function

I am trying to achieve this problem: EDITED

**a. Create a program that will compute an electric bill.**

**b. Let the user provide the following data:**

- account name
- address
- type
- previous reading
- present reading
- date of bill

***`-For residential, rate per kilowatt will be P15.50 while business is P25.75.`***

**c. Create a subfunction for the following:**

- inputting of the above account details
- computation of bill
- display of the account information,
- current consumed kilowatt and
- the  billing amount for the month.

**d. Example Output:**

Enter name: Juan Cruz

Enter address: Nasipit, Adn

Type (Residential or Business): Residential

Previous Reading: 10

Present Reading: 15

Date of Bill: March 15, 2022

```
Display:
```

Account name: Juan Cruz

Address: Nasipit, Adn

Type: Residential

Date: March 15, 2022

Previous Reading: 10

Present Reading: 15

Consumed Kilowatt: 5

Amount Billed: P77.50

Formulas: consumed_kilowatt=present_reading-previous_reading

billed_amount=consumed_kilowatt*rate_per_kilowatt

Here's the code so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>

void details(char* info);
float consumed(float a, float b);
float business(float a);
float residence(float a);

void main(){
    float prev, pres;
    float billed_amount, consumed_kilowatt;
    char* info[200];
    char bus[]="Business", res[]="Residential";
    char *acc_nm, *add, *type, *prevread, *presread, *date;
    char account_info[25];
    
    details(info);
    
    prev=atof(prevread);
    pres=atof(presread);
    
    consumed_kilowatt=consumed(pres, prev);
    if(!strcmp(type,bus)){
        billed_amount=business(consumed_kilowatt);
    } else {
        billed_amount=residence(consumed_kilowatt);
    }
    
    }

void details(char* info){
    char array[][20] = { "Account Name", "Address", "Type", "Previous Reading", "Present Reading", "Date"};
    int i;
    
    printf("Please provide your data by following the format: Account_Name, Address(St_Brgy_City_State), Type(Residential or Business), Previousreading, PresentReading, Date(MM/DD/YYYY)");
    printf("\n\nNote: Please make sure to follow format. Avoid unnecessary spaces and symbols.\n\n");
    
    for (i=0; i<6; i++){
        printf("Enter %s: ", array[i]);
        scanf("%s", &info[i]);
    }

}

float consumed(float a, float b){
    float read;
    
    read=a-b;
    return read;
}

float business(float a){
    float business=25.75, val;
    
    val=a*business;
    return val;
}

float residence(float a){
    float residence=15.50, val;
    
    val=a*residence;
    return val;
}
```

I am trying to use the values I collected as an array in `details()` within the `void main()` so I can compute `consumed_kilowatt` and `billed_amount formulas`.

as you can see I am new to c programming. I have been reading online resources only and I really don't have any idea where should I start learning. I found this challenge and I thought of trying this out but I can't seem to get it.

Comment: `char* info[200];` declares an array of char pointers.  You want `char info[200]`, which declares an array of characters.  When you pass `info` to a function, it will decay to a pointer to its first element.  The compiler should warn you about this when you attempt to pass `info` to `details`, since `details` expect a char * but you are passing the wrong type.

Comment: If you change the argument type in `details` to accept an array of pointers (which seems to be what you want, given the way you are using `scanf`), those pointers must be initialized.  With `char *info[200]`, you get 200 uninitialized pointers.  They don't point to valid memory.  Passing them as arguments to `scanf` instructs scanf to write data to those locations, but they aren't referencing a writable address, so you get undefined behavior.

Comment: @WilliamPursell i am trying to get the values of the array from `details` and pass it to the main function so I can use a specific value of the array for my computations, I don't know how or what should I change in the code since I'm literally a beginner. if you could site sources related to the problem within the code I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What do you suppose `prev=atof(prevread); pres=atof(presread);` will do? You are using ***a lot*** of uninitialized variables.

Comment: Tip: Use `-Wall` and/or `-Wextra` flags on your compilation.

Comment: @anastaciu I actually declared the prev and pres. since the value was originally a string from details function, I want to convert them into float so I can then use it in my formula, I googled it, let me know if I did it right :)

Comment: @ANGELICAViajedor I would prefer [`strtod()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof) as it's safer than atof. Note that in C, declaring a variable and initializing a variable are two different things, acting on an unitialized variable amounts to [undefined behavior](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3). In the code you show, that is the case, IDK if that's the case in your current code, but if it is you should take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

There are inconsistencies in the parameter you are passing to `details`.  That function is declared to accept a `char *`, but you are passing it an array of pointers.  But the function you have written seems to expect an array of char *, rather than the `char *` that it is defined to take.  I think you are looking for something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void details(char (*info)[200]);

struct column {
    char header[20];
    char format[40];
};

struct column c[] = {
    { "Account Name", "" },
    { "Address", " (St_Brgy_City_State)" },
    { "Type", " (Residential or Business)" },
    { "Previous Reading", "" },
    { "Present Reading", "" },
    { "Date", " (MM/DD/YYYY)" }
};
int
main(void)
{
    char info[6][200];
    details(info);
    for( int i = 0; i < 6; i++ ){
        printf("%20s: %s\n", c[i].header, info[i]);
    }
}

void
details(char (*info)[200])
{
    int i;

    printf("%s", "Please provide your data by following the format: ");
    for( i = 0; i < 6; i++ ){
        printf("%s%s%s", c[i].header, c[i].format, i == 5 ? "\n" : ", ");
    }
    printf("Note: Please make sure to follow format. Avoid unnecessary spaces and symbols.\n\n");

    for( i = 0; i < 6; i++ ){
        printf("Enter %s: ", c[i].header);
        if( scanf(" %199[^\n]", info[i]) != 1 ){
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `scanf` is a terrible tool.  You will be much happier if you abandon its use now.  Learning its foibles will not help you learn the language and will merely cause hours and hours of pointless frustration.